# CoffeeScript Resources to Write Cleaner Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to create a cleaner and better Node.js (Coffeescript) code. There are a lot of examples like [hubot](https://github.com/github/hubot) but none that explains how everything plays together.

Is there any codebase with documentation, or books or other resources that teaches you how to develop clean CoffeeScript code (everything by files, classes, error handling, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Hubot is a really good example. The annotated source for CoffeeScript itself is also good (click "Annotated Source" at http://coffeescript.org/). I wrote a [book on CoffeeScript](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript) that examples of both a front-end CoffeeScript app with jQuery, and a back-end app with Node.js.

Other resources you should be aware of:

- The [CoffeeScript Cookbook](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/) (a curated wiki)
- The [Little Book on CoffeeScript](http://arcturo.github.com/library/coffeescript/) (which covers [classes](http://arcturo.github.com/library/coffeescript/03_classes.html) quite well)

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know is on the official CoffeeScript website, here: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#resources